# Comparing population averages while accounting for changes in composition

Tags: bayesian, estimation, mean, population, latent-variable

I have two populations (i.e., men / women) with different average measurements (let's say height). I observe the combined average of their height decreases. I also observe the proportion of women increasing.

I want to account for the how much of the decreased average height is due to the increased proportion of women, and how much of it is due to other factors. How best do I do this?

Comment: What do you mean by volume changes? Observing more data with different proportions than is the distribution you observed initially?

Comment: @JanKukacka that's exactly what I mean. Thanks for helping me clarify.

Comment: I assume you mean "... *decreased* average height..." in the last paragraph.

Comment: You don't seem to want a test, just to estimate the influence of a latent variable (set of variables) while taking into account the uncertainty in the previously observed distributions. That sounds like a Bayesian estimation problem. It might help if you could post a small example dataset for people to work with.